# How to update adapter items in viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `viewPager()` which have 3 pages, it have a `recyclerView` and each page have three different adapters and i want something like when user clicks on adapter item in first page it adds in a database and second adapter gets its array list from the same database, but it shows in second page's adapter after app restarts, so the question is how to update the second page's adapter without restart.

Comment: Did you call `notifyDatasetChange` or others function which trigger the `RecyclerView` update it UI when data has been changed?

Comment: Ya `notifyDatasetChange` Doesn't work

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

A regular `ListView` can use a `CursorAdapter` which provides some of the functions you need. Alas, there is no existing `CursorAdapter` class that extends  `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

The quickest solution would be to use `RecyclerViewCursorAdapter` on GitHub.

Then it would work something like this:

- Update your database
- Get a reference to your second page fragment.  You can store this reference when you create the fragment in `getItem()`.  Note that your fragment could be null depending on what pages the `ViewPager` has/hasn't created.
- Call a method on your fragment that will create a new `Cursor` to be used by the adapter (with the same query as before).  When the adapter receives the new `Cursor` it will update the `RecyclerView`.